# How to make text adapt to its surrounding shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, text

Are there any special techniques used to make these types of logos?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign! Have you tried researching it or trying anything? Showing effort will likely get you better replies

Comment: [Here's a related article](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-typography-illustrations-the-easy-way) that delves into how to do something similar in Illustrator

Comment: Thanks a lot @ZachSaucier. Excellent article, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that both of the examples you provided began with a hand-drawn sketch that was then scanned in and created in Adobe Illustrator.

The book [Lettering and Type](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/156898765X) is a good resource for beginning to explore custom lettering.

Comment: There are ways to do it using only editors like PS or Illustrator

Comment: There are ways to use an editor only, but I've never seen it work to the level of polish as the examples provided without the human hand.